# chrome and bluetooth - connecting, discovering - how to make it working?

Tags: google-chrome, web, bluetooth

I am working on project that would discover nearby bluetooth devices via webpage.

Here are my limitations:
- development under windows 7 or 10, android 5 on phone
- peripheral is bluetooth beacon
- central is phone with android 6

First of all i made a page looking like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="target" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red"></div>

<script>
$('#target').click(function() { 
  chrome.bluetooth.startDiscovery(function () { 
  navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services:['battery_service'] }] })
  .then(device => {

    console.log(device);
  return device.gatt.connect();
  }).then(server => { console.log(server)}).catch(error  => { console.log(error); });
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This piece of code lets me to pair bluetooth device with service called "battery_service" with webpage. And it is working (morover) - it opens "chrome system" window for searching nearby devices and finds one if only i have already paired it in windows. If it wasnt paired earlier it will find nothing. Chrome says that gatt server doesnt exist so i can not connect it, and object has gatt property that has gatt property that has gatt property (and so on to the infinity)

Anyways it returns `device` object containing `device.name` and `device.id` property. Other properties are `undefined`.

None of any examples i found on internet have been working for me.

So here are questions:

1. is it possible to use windows as development platform?
2. is it possible to use android 5 to be bluetooth perpiheral?
3. what is the difference between chrome.bluetooth object and navigator.bluetooth object? Every tutorial uses chrome.bluetooth however it is undefined object in my chrome browser. Navigator.bluetooth works as mentioned before.
4. i've found chrome.bluetooth.startDiscovery but navigator.bluetooth doesnt have such method, and chrome.bluetooth is empty object i can not discover it at all. Because i do not want even to connect to devices, but only know its presence is it possible not to pair the devices each time it comes into the bluetooth range?
5. are there any working examples?
6. should be windows pairing enough? Do we need for security reasons pair devices in chrome that are already paired by operating system?

I use CHROME 56.0.2924.76 64bit.

Thanks for any help!
Kalreg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start by saying **Windows 10 support for Web Bluetooth is <strike>coming in a near future</strike> now available**. Check out regularly the [Web Bluetooth implementation status](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md#chrome) page for that.

Re: your issue, you are combining there the [Bluetooth Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth) (for Chrome Apps) and the [Web Bluetooth API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web). Since Windows 10 support is not complete yet, you'll have hard time to connect to a GATT Server.

> 1. is it possible to use windows as development platform?

Not for now. Soon yes.

> 2. is it possible to use android 5 to be bluetooth perpiheral?

Yes. I do that all the time with [BLE Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral) Android app.

> 3. what is the difference between chrome.bluetooth object and
>      navigator.bluetooth object? Every tutorial uses chrome.bluetooth
>      however it is undefined object in my chrome browser.
>      Navigator.bluetooth works as mentioned before.

`chrome.bluetooth` is only available in [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) while `navigator.bluetooth` is available to Chrome Apps & websites since this a Web API.

> 4. i've found chrome.bluetooth.startDiscovery but navigator.bluetooth
>      doesnt have such method, and chrome.bluetooth is empty object i can
>      not discover it at all. Because i do not want even to connect to
>      devices, but only know its presence is it possible not to pair the
>      devices each time it comes into the bluetooth range?

`navigator.bluetooth` has the `requestDevice` method to start scanning. This will pop-up a chooser from which the user can pick a device. Look at this [device info sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html)

> 5. are there any working examples?

There are plenty at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wasnt aware that i can chrome apps for android. Will chromapps work for IOS too? I can write my code on windows and upload it as chrome app to my iphone/android phone and check it there - it is even better for me. 
1. will it work on chrome for ios?
2. is in chrome apps startdiscovery also making a popup choser? or does it check in background? I just need to know presence of beacons, no connection needed
3. Do i need some priviliges or pay to apple to have my app existing in appstore?

Comment: Chrome Apps do NOT work for Android. See https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html to learn more about the future of Chrome Apps.

Comment: chrome apps startdiscovery doesn't show a popup chooser. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth#method-startDiscovery

Comment: i am a bit concerned - i watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU4lvgTrjFI and google employee discovers advantages of google chrome's apps runing on android and developed on any platform. Is this going to stop working?

Comment: As you can read at https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps#create-chrome-apps-for-mobile-using-apache-cordova, _The Chrome Apps for Mobile Toolchain is no longer being actively developed._

Comment: anyway it works so it's good to go for me :) fight continous :D thank you for your help. i will monitor development of web bluetooth api

Comment: Still not possible to use windows as development platform?

Comment: @l2aelba Done ;)